# Pyspark Failed to find data source: kafka

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming-kafka

I am working on Kafka streaming and trying to integrate it with Apache Spark. However, while running I am getting into issues. I am getting the below error.

This is the command I am using.

`df_TR = Spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092").option("subscribe", "taxirides").load()`

ERROR:

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o77.load.: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: kafka. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html

How can I resolve this?

NOTE: I am running this in Jupyter Notebook

```
findspark.init('/home/karan/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7')
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
Spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('KafkaStreaming').getOrCreate()
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
```

Everything is running fine till here (above code)

`df_TR = Spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092").option("subscribe", "taxirides").load()`

This is where things are going wrong (above code).

The blog which I am following: https://www.adaltas.com/en/2019/04/18/spark-streaming-data-pipelines-with-structured-streaming/

Answer (score 10):

**Edit**

Using `spark.jars.packages` works better than `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS`

Ref - [PySpark - NoClassDefFoundError: kafka/common/TopicAndPartition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72627688/pyspark-noclassdeffounderror-kafka-common-topicandpartition/72639163#72639163)

---

It's not clear how you ran the code. Keep reading the blog, and you see

```
spark-submit \
  ...
  --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.0 \
  sstreaming-spark-out.py
```

Seems you missed adding the `--packages` flag

In Jupyter, you could add this

```
import os

# setup arguments
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.0'

# initialize spark
import pyspark, findspark
findspark.init()
```

Note: `_2.11:2.4.0` need to align with your Scala and Spark versions... Based on the question, yours should be Spark 2.1.0

Comment: Post adding import OS, I am getting another error now.                                                                               Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o27.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: kafka.

Comment: @PKernel This is because the version of spark-sql-kafka does not match the spark version you are currently running.