# Issue in Kafka to Spark Streaming Data pipeline with python pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming-kafka

I am using below program and runnign this in Anaconda(Spyder) for creating data pipeline from   Kafka to Spark streaming & in python

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
from uuid import uuid1
import os


##Step 1: Initialize sparkcontext
spark_context = SparkContext(appName="Transformation Application")

###Step 2: Initialize streaming context
ssc = StreamingContext(spark_context, 5)

def utf8_decoder(s):
    """ Decode the unicode as UTF-8 """
    if s is None:
        return None
    return s.decode('utf-8')

message = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc,topics=['testtopic'],kafkaParams={"metadata.broker.list":"localhost:9092","key.deserializer": "org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer","value.deserializer": "org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer"},fromOffsets=None,messageHandler=None,keyDecoder=utf8_decoder,valueDecoder=utf8_decoder)
message
words = message.map(lambda x: x[1]).flatMap(lambda x: x.split(" "))
wordcount=words.map(lambda x: (x,1)).reduceByKey(lambda a,b:a+b)
wordcount.pprint()
```

When I am printing message, words,wordscount  i am getting no proper results,I am getting hexadecimal values .

```
message
Out[16]: <pyspark.streaming.kafka.KafkaDStream at 0x23f8b1f8248>

wordcount
Out[18]: <pyspark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream at 0x23f8b2324c8>
```

in my topic(testtopic) I am produced string - " Hi Hi Hi how are you doing"  then wordcount should give count for each word but it is giving some encoded hexadecimal values

Comment: What did you expect the line with just `message` to do? You're printing the Python object, not consuming the stream... Also, Spark has its own json functions, you shouldn't need to (try to) import Spring serializers

Comment: @OneCricketeer   Sorry I am new to spark and kafka both..it means message output is fine. but printing wordcount and words both also giving TransformedDStream  object..While wordcount  should give counts of all words like 3 for Hi and 1 for each rest word for Topic with string produced as "my topic(testtopic) I am produced string - " Hi Hi Hi how are you doing"...  Also If I have to create data pipeline from kafka>Spark Streaming>MYSQL DB   then how can I make sure that data is kafka topic is avilable in Spark where can I see that data in Spark.   Please help to guide on this.

Comment: My point is that you're printing an object, which is a Python "problem", unrelated to spark or Kafka... `wordcount.pprint()` is correct if you want to actually see the data

Comment: @OneCricketeer  Thanks Sir...Just one last question Can we convert  message (Kafka direct stream) into spark data frame ? I have to store my streaming records in my sql.Since spark dataframe can be stored to mysql DB so thats why asking

Comment: You should be using Structured Streaming if you want to do that. Alternatively, Kafka Connect is provided by Kafka and you can use that to write to mysql as well

Comment: @OneCricketeer  

 Thanks Sir I am trying to use now Structured Streaming.
 I am using Spark structured Streaming to read data from Kafka topic.
 Spark version(Local windows machine): 2.3.4
 kafka version: Confluence 6.6.0(kafka 2.6)
 Jar Version : Jar -spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.4.jar (placed in jar folder of spark).

Getting this  Error.Is my jar version is correct.
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o81.load. : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class

Comment: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o81.load. : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$ at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider.validateStreamOptions(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:360) at

Comment: Don't manually add jar files. Use `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS` environment variable. For example https://stackoverflow.com/a/58723724/2308683

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks Sir now it worked .Now able to read data from kafka and created spark streaming dataframe.But wjhen tried to write in mysql (df.write.jdbc )it is giving error "AnalysisException: "'write' can not be called on streaming Dataset/DataFrame;"" .is there any example or reference code on writing streaming pyspark dataframe into Mysql or any other DB.

Comment: writeStream, not write